# Unable to edit datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

My API is serving datetime as '2010-07-01T00:00:00.000Z' , i have used the following code

```
for d in df['date']:
    d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df = df.set_index('date')
```

but it doesnt work. I have used d.strftime before, how to deal with this

Comment: You are not doing anything with the result of `strftime` should you be assigning it to `d`? `d = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: How to do it then? and the format for datetime is not date64 but object.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What is `type(df)` and `type(df['date'])` and what is `df.set_index()` for (if it is relevant to the question)?

Comment: (df['date']) is a dataframe column containing datetime string objects in format '2010-07-01T00:00:00.000Z' , i want to edit it to 2010-07-01'. @jhutar

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but think you can do:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although question + comments is bit unclear, I think this could help.

If `df['date']` is a string:

```
>>> df = {'date': '2010-07-01T00:00:00.000Z'}
>>> df['date'] = df['date'].split('T')[0]
>>> df
{'date': '2010-07-01'}
```

If `df['date']` is datetime object and we only want date part of it as a string:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> df = {'date': datetime.datetime.now()}
>>> df
{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 31, 10, 32, 51, 464469)}
>>> df['date'] = df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> df
{'date': '2021-01-31'}
```

Also question indicates `df['date']` is a list of datetime objects, so lets say you want biggest one:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> df = {'date': [datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()]}
>>> df['date'] = max(df['date']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> df
{'date': '2021-01-31'}
```